# sql select could use if?

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my sql

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN C ON C.ID2 = B.ID2
WHERE ( 
        (
          C.ST_DT >= TO_DATE('2014/04/08 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
          AND
          C.ST_DT < TO_DATE('2014/04/09 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
        ) 
      ) 
OR ( 
     (
          C.ST_DT <= TO_DATE('2014/04/08 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
          AND
          C.EN_DT > TO_DATE('2014/04/09 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
     ) 
   )
AND C.IS_MAIN = '1'
```

**---Edit-----------------------------------------------------------------------------**

I got this result

```
ID ID2 ST_DT                EN_DT                TYPE  MOD_DT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  a1  2014/04/01 14:00:00  2014/04/10 14:00:00  0     2014/04/01 10:00:00
2  a1  2014/04/01 14:30:00  2014/04/10 14:00:00  1     2014/04/01 09:00:00
3  b1  2014/03/03 14:30:00  2014/04/15 14:00:00  1     2014/03/08 10:00:00
4  c4  2014/03/05 14:30:00  2014/04/20 14:00:00  1     2014/04/08 10:00:00
5  a1  2014/03/23 14:40:00  2014/03/30 14:00:00  0     2014/03/24 10:00:00
```

I want get this result

```
ID ID2 ST_DT                EN_DT                TYPE  MOD_DT
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
3  b1  2014/03/03 14:30:00  2014/04/15 14:00:00  1     2014/03/08 10:00:00
4  c4  2014/03/05 14:30:00  2014/04/20 14:00:00  1     2014/04/08 10:00:00
5  a1  2014/03/23 14:40:00  2014/03/30 14:00:00  0     2014/03/24 10:00:00
```

The origin ID 1 and 2 I don't want get. Because the ID 1's `MOD_DT < ST_DT` AND TYPE is 0. But I want get the ID 5.

Can I add `if` after where...? Thanks.

Comment: You can use case in SQL statements but not if. What you want can be achieved through where condition. `select a1 from table_name where mod_dt < st_dt and type = 0`

Comment: Oracle doesn't support IF in SQL, but you can use CASE instead

Comment: Can you please write your if and condition it is not so clear?

Comment: Do you want to see `a1` row or don't see that?

Comment: Can I add `if` after where? I have edit my question.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, Just added one more condition in you script.

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN C ON C.ID2 = B.ID2
WHERE ( 
        (
          C.ST_DT >= TO_DATE('2014/04/08 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
          AND
          C.ST_DT < TO_DATE('2014/04/09 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
        ) 
      ) 
OR ( 
     (
          C.ST_DT <= TO_DATE('2014/04/08 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') 
          AND
          C.EN_DT > TO_DATE('2014/04/09 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')
     ) 
   )
AND C.IS_MAIN = '1'
and (
        (MOD_DT < ST_DT and TYPE =0)
        OR 
        1=1

    )
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a parentheses.  You have `X OR Y AND Z` as your conditional.  It needs to be `(X OR Y) AND Z`.  It doesn't help that you have extra parentheses as well.

```
SELECT * FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
INNER JOIN C ON C.ID2 = B.ID2
WHERE (
        (C.ST_DT >= TO_DATE('2014/04/08 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AND C.ST_DT < TO_DATE('2014/04/09 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')) 
        OR 
        (C.ST_DT <= TO_DATE('2014/04/08 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss') AND C.EN_DT > TO_DATE('2014/04/09 00:00:00', 'yyyy/mm/dd hh24:mi:ss')) 
    )
    AND C.IS_MAIN = '1'
```